# will CSS transitions override each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have two `col-md-6` class and each contains a button in it, upon clicking, im using jQuery to `toggleClass()` of one between `col-md-6` and `col-md-12` and hide/show the other. I also use CSS transition to animate the toggling, but it would work for one class and if I click the other button, the transition is not working.

Does multiple class selector cause issue with transitions?

```
.hello, .bye{
   -webkit-transition: width 500ms;
   -moz-transition: width 500ms;
   -o-transition: width 500ms;
   transition: width 500ms;
}
```

Here's the problem in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtmx15nq/)

Comment: A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Added

Comment: seems to be working for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, so I took it upon myself and made some necessary changes to your code, so that the end result will resemble a lot what you (most likely) have in your mind.

**CSS Notes:**

- To avoid having **`#btn1`** and **`#btn2`** overflow **`.hello`** and **`.bye`** respectively, you need to use **`overflow: hidden`**.
- To avoid having **`.hello`** and **`.bye`** wrapping during the transition if there's not enough room for both, you need to use: **`padding: 0`**.
- If you want your buttons to remain at the exact position they were (15px indented), use: **`margin-left: 15px`**.

**CSS Code:**

```
.hello,
.bye {
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 500ms;
    -moz-transition: width 500ms;
    -o-transition: width 500ms;
    transition: width 500ms;
}

#btn1,
#btn2 {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

---

**JS Notes:**

- Your code is kind of inefficient as you basically repeat the same code over and over, so I created a function for you that can be used for both buttons.

**JS Code:**

Check out the full JavaScript code in the following:

- **Codepen:** → [here](http://codepen.io/angelpolitis/pen/YWdjgJ);
- **jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw0Lpgy5/1/);

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to work on this issue, maybe my question is bit vague. Your code does exactly what I was looking for, except in Codepen, if you rapidly click the button, sometimes the red div would go under the yellow div.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you have with the **`codepen`**, but as far as I'm concerned there is no reason for somebody to click a button so rapidly unless they are testing it. You can limit clicking the button once every **`500ms`** if you want, and this will get rid of the issue you are having without any visual difference for the user.

Comment: I have accept the answer and thanks again. Maybe its the browser size that causes the issue.